# How can I use a query to determine if a function is scalar in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I can't figure out how to get a list of scalar functions in a postgres database.

I've tried to write different queries, but I can't find an exact solution to determine the scalar type returned by a function.
So far the only solution that has come to mind is filtering the name of the function return type with a regular expression.

Comment: why not show what you have tried so far

Comment: These attempts will not carry sufficient semantic load. I need a brainstorm

Comment: What does "scalar" mean to you exactly? Are you trying to figure out whether it might return multiple rows? Does an array count, does a cursor count?

Comment: Your prior attempts might not carry sufficient semantic load; however, not presenting them carries **NO** semantic load. Showing your prior attempts helps the SO community understand where you are in your exploration of a solution. As @Bergi asked, what does _scalar_ mean in this context? In most programming contexts, _scalar_ types would exclude arrays, records, sets, tables, and other collections of values. Consider querying the system catalogs `pg_proc` and `pg_type` and filtering on attributes of `pg_type`.

Comment: By scalar I mean a function that returns one value: integer, float, etc. An array is several values

Comment: @Flex1sh Then use zegarek's answer and also join against [`pg_type`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-type.html) where you can check with `typcategory <> 'A'` whether that type is not an array. But if you look at the details, there's a large grey area: would you consider a composite type to be a "single value"? What about a range? What about `jsonb` which can be both a single number or an array, distinguishable only at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by *scalar* you mean non-set-returning, system catalog [`pg_proc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-proc.html) column `proretset` can tell you that: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/DEbWG49Y)

```sql
select oid::regprocedure, prorettype::regtype 
from pg_proc where not proretset and prokind in ('a','f','w');
```

`('a','f','w')` mean aggregate, regular and window functions. It's worth taking a look at return types because with the definition assumed above, a function that `returns void`, `returns trigger`, `returns cursor` is also scalar.

The standard [`information_schema.routines`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-routines.html) does not differentiate between scalar and non-scalar functions in any way.